# How to multitask commands for MobaXterm with a .bat file

Tags: command-prompt, mobaxterm

I want to start mobaxterm and then start a ssh and then want to see the que list (which is done by "qstat -wa") and finally want to see the files in it (which is done by "ls").

For this purpose, I've started to create a bat file. But I could not find a way to assign multiple task in the bat file. For now, I only get the correct ssh I want (which is shown below). How can I add the other tasks in sequence I've told in the first paragraph above?

```
@echo off
mobaXterm -newtab "ssh xxx.com.tr"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save your session in Moba and under Advanced SSH settings you'll have field Executed command: which does exactly what you need.

[Executed command:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXVYK.png)

You don't even need an extra bat file as you can save your session directly from Moba saved session under Bookmark settings.

[Create a desktop shortcut to this session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hA3l.png)